# Magento 2.1.6 : Exception For Writing Image Files on Local Wamp , Log is Given in Comment Box

Tags: magento2, image

main.CRITICAL: exception **'Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException' with message 'Directory "D:/UwAmp/www/magento2_1_6/D:**" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Invalid argument' in `D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php:225`
Stack trace:

`0 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php(218): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('D:/UwAmp/www/ma...', 511)`

`1 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php(218): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('D:/UwAmp/www/ma...', 511)`

`2 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php(218): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('D:/UwAmp/www/ma...', 511)`

`3 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php(218): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('D:/UwAmp/www/ma...', 511)`

`4 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php(218): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('D:/UwAmp/www/ma...', 511)`

`5 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php(218): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('D:/UwAmp/www/ma...', 511)`

`6 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php(218): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('D:/UwAmp/www/ma...', 511)`

`7 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php(218): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('D:/UwAmp/www/ma...', 511)`

`8 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php(218): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('D:/UwAmp/www/ma...', 511)`

`9 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php(218): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('D:/UwAmp/www/ma...', 511)`

`10 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php(218): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('D:/UwAmp/www/ma...', 511)`

`11 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php(199): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('D:/UwAmp/www/ma...', 511)`

`12 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write.php(89): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->createDirectory('D:/UwAmp/www/ma...', 511)`

`13 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\AbstractAdapter.php(684): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->create('/D:/UwAmp/www/m...')`

`14 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php(141): Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AbstractAdapter->_prepareDestination('\\D:/UwAmp/www/m...', NULL)`

`15 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Image.php(79): Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2->save('\\D:/UwAmp/www/m...', NULL)`

`16 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product\Image.php(677): Magento\Framework\Image->save('\\D:/UwAmp/www/m...')`

`17 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Image.php(465): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image->saveFile()`

`18 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Image.php(534): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->applyScheduledActions()`

`19 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder.php(132): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->getResizedImageInfo()`

`20 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct.php(517): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder->create()`

`21 D:\UwAmp\www\magento2_1_6\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct->getImage(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), 'new_products_co...', Array)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running deployment, upgrade and Clearing Cache in development mode solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command from Magento CLI.

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I ran that command, Still i am gettting message as
Unable to write file into directory \D:/UwAmp/www/magento2_1_6/pub/media/catalog
/product\cache\914b1ba9268f8c1d0e58a8e7ce614488\/m/h. Access forbidden.
I am at adminstrator account to o and i think there should be no issue with permission!!!

Comment: @TejasVyas please set proper permission of media folder.

Comment: Permission is upto date.